# How to get count of items in rows as well as check one item is present or not, and finally keep the first row in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, calculated-columns

Suppose I have a data frame as follows:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Column A': [12,12,12, 13, 15, 16, 141, 141, 141, 141],
         'Column B':['Apple' ,'Apple' ,'Orange' ,'Apple' , np.nan, 'Orange', 'Apple', np.nan, 'Apple', 'Apple']})
```

Based on these conditions:

- If values in column A are repeated then count the word 'Orange' in Column B and paste it in new Column C(For example, there are 3 rows for 12, the count of 'Orange' is 1, and this 1 should be in new column C). For the non-repeat rows, just paste the corresponding values.
- If values in column A are repeated then count the word 'Apple' in Column B and paste it in new Column D(For example, there are 3 rows for 12, the count of 'Apple' is 2, and this 2 should be in new column D). For the non-repeat rows, just paste the corresponding values.
- For repeated and non-repeated rows due to Column A, If the word 'Orange' is present in Column B, write 'yes' else 'No' in Column E.

I would like to have an output following. I was trying in python jupyter notebook, can anyone please help me to get an output like this:

```
      | Column A | Column B |Column C |Column D |Column E 
----- | -------- | ---------|---------|---------|---------
 0    | 12       | Apple    |1        |2        |Yes   
 1    | 13       | Apple    |0        |1        |No 
 2    | 15       | NaN      |NaN      |NaN      |NaN     
 3    | 16       | Orange   |1        |0        |Yes      
 4    | 141      | Apple    |0        |3        |No
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: One question. How to determine the value of column B? I mean there are Apple and Orange in row 0 - 2, but Orange is removed after removing duplicates

Comment: Column B is the value of the first row of the repeating rows and non-repeating rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no powerful and simple solution for your question, but use the following code.

First, define a function `count(x, a)` which returns `nan` if x includes `nan`, the number of occurence of a in x, otherwise.
The function will be used for the apply function.

Then, use groupby and apply list function.

```
temp = df.copy().groupby('Column A')['Column B'].apply(list)
```

After that, temp becomes

```
Column A
12         [Apple, Apple, Orange]
13                        [Apple]
15                          [nan]
16                       [Orange]
141    [Apple, nan, Apple, Apple]
Name: Column B, dtype: object
```

So, based on the temp, we can count the number of apples and oranges.

Since df has duplicates, I removed them and add new columns (Column C, D, and E).

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Column A'], keep = "first", inplace = True)
df['Column C'] = temp.apply(count, a = "Orange").values
df['Column D'] = temp.apply(count, a = "Apple").values
df['Column E'] = df['Column D'].apply(lambda x:1 if x>=1 else 0)
```

**Edit**

I am sorry. I missed the function count..

```
def count(x, a):
    if type(x[0]) == float:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x.count(a)
```

Comment: Now I am getting the output as below and which is right. 

0    1.0
3    0.0
4    NaN
5    1.0
6    0.0

is it possible to change the left side number  0 3 4 5 6  of counted values to 0 1 2 3 4 5?